# RegEx for Positive Lookahead - password rules (contains required numbers and characters)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I'd like to understand the below regex and tried testing it in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/2rw308/1)

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{4,}$
```

Comment: there is an explanation section in regex101

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That regex doesn't mean much and can be shortened to:

```
.{4,}$ // match at least 4 characters (or more) before ending
```

The reason is that *lookaheads* define where your matching group pattern *ends*. But you are placing the lookahead at the start of the input string, catching "" (nothing) in front of all the lookahead patterns. So all the *lookaheads* are redundant.

So:

> `^` pattern must start at the beginning of input
>
> `(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` find lookahead of any number of consecutive alphabets (found "TestPassword", **not** to be included in matching group)
>
> `(?=.*[0-9])` find lookahead of any number of digits (found "1", **not** to be included in matching group)
>
> Given above, the only match is "" at the beginning of "TestPassword1". Now we continue the matching...
>
> `.{4,}$` now match anything of at least 4 characters situated right at the end of 
>   input (found "TestPassword1", which *is* returned as matching group)

See below code for proof and explanation:

```js
let regex = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{4,}$/;
[match] = "TestPassword1".match(regex);
console.log(match); //TestPassword1

// just test for lookaheads result in matching an empty string at the start of input (before "T")
regex = /^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])/;
match = "TestPassword1".match(regex);
console.log(match); //[""]

// we're now testing for at least 4 characters of anything just before the end of input
regex = /.{4,}$/;
[match] = "TestPassword1".match(regex);
console.log(match); //TestPassword1
```

Answer (score -1):

Explained

```
 ^                        # BOS
 (?= .* [a-zA-Z] )        # Lookahead, must be a letter
 (?= .* [0-9] )           # Lookahead, must be a number
 .{4,}                    # Any 4 or more characters 
 $                        # EOS
```

Comment: I knew about result. but i didn't understand rules of `positive lookahead`. `regex1(?=regex2)` that is first search `regex1` and if exists `regex2`. but `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{4,}$` ...

Comment: No worries, we've all been there and regex is not easy and can't be grasped in one day. Just take baby steps, one step at a time and you'll get better and better. You can start with resources on the web like https://regexone.com.

Comment: @greenb - Assertions and other non-consuming constructs, don't actually exist at character positions. They exist _between_ characters. It is a subject I've written about here at SO, but I just can't find the link to it. It's too bad, maybe you could find it, it would help you to forever understand these ghosts.

Comment: @sln Thank you very much. I understood from your comment :)